# c# Combobox displays System.Data.Datarowview because of point

Tags: c#, sql

this is code which give an error

```
        DataSet Music = new DataSet();
        Music= DBI.musicall();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember= "music1.name";   // with .
        comboBox1.ValueMember="Id";
        comboBox1.DataSource=Music.Tables[0];
```

this is the code which is working.

```
        DataSet Music = new DataSet();
        Music= DBI.musicall();
        comboBox1.DisplayMember= "music1name";  // no point -- no  . 
        comboBox1.ValueMember="Id";
        comboBox1.DataSource=Music.Tables[0];


  public static DataSet musicall()
    {
        SqlConnection connect= new SqlConnection(connectway);

        string sql = "select *from Music";
       SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand();
       command.CommandText=sql;
       command.Connection=connect;

        SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adaptor.SelectCommand=command;
        DataSet finalDs= new DataSet();
        connect.Open();
        adaptor.Fill(finalDs);
        connect.Close();
        return finalDs;

    }
```

Why do I encounter with this problem when i use the  point(.) in the column name.

Why when i use  " . " in column name, combobox displays that mistake ?

I can fix this problem without using " . " but i  dont want to fix this like that.

Comment: Where is the code for `musicall();` ??

Comment: What is `CREATE TABLE` for Music?

Comment: I did. sorry for that.
Yes i did. I said its already works when i dont use the  " . "

Comment: Does the datatable have column with name "music1.name" ?

Comment: Yes. there is "music1.name" music1.price" "music1.artist" (columns name)
Table name is : Music

Comment: I told you , show us the `create table`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/5dc3c708084709efbd490c06ca0b8fa6.png
Like that ?

Comment: What error you get when using the `.`. In your picture is called `music.name` here you use `music1.name` ??

Comment: BTW, you shouldnt name your field `music.name` the field is already in the `music` table so is redundant.

Comment: Oh sorry. I changed it already. I'm using music.name in my code. It's not  just about the music.name. It has a problem with all columns which has " . " I'm trying a way for figure it. But didnt find it

Comment: You should just know that. I cant use  '. ' in my column names. Thats my all problem. Its already working without problem. I Just, i want to use " ."

Comment: It might not be supported by .NET databinding logic because `DisplayMember` expects a name of the property which it should look in the datasource while binding combobox. And as per the standard rule property can not have dot (.) in it. This causes failure of finding property and its value. And that's why it does display the standard string representation. If you check the SelectedValue property of combobox you should be getting proper value coz "Id" is a valid property name.

Comment: Yes, you could be right. I have same problem in the query already. 
select *from Music where music.name  ='Sunshine' . this not working but it should work.
select *from Music where [music.name]  ='Sunshine' But this is working :)
Because i used [ ] .  Its just because of  (.)  I gave up. I dont use (.) anymore

Comment: @Australopithecus, can you consider _(instead using *)_ declare each column of your table as follows? `select music.name AS [MusicName] FROM Music`

Comment: Have you tried:  comboBox1.DisplayMember= "[music1.name]";   ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather do this:

```
    DataSet Music = new DataSet();
    Music= DBI.musicall();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember= "music1name";  
    comboBox1.ValueMember="Id";
    comboBox1.DataSource=Music.Tables[0];

public static DataSet musicall()
{
    SqlConnection connect= new SqlConnection(connectway);

    string sql = "select [music1.name] AS music1name from Music";
   SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand();
   command.CommandText=sql;
   command.Connection=connect;

    SqlDataAdapter adaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adaptor.SelectCommand=command;
    DataSet finalDs= new DataSet();
    connect.Open();
    adaptor.Fill(finalDs);
    connect.Close();
    return finalDs;

}
```